# Can I have a JavaScript object key without a value

Tags: javascript, json

I am wanting to store TaskPaper-like tasks in a JavaScript object. Suppose I have a task like

```
- Post to StackOverflow @priority(2) @due(2016-05-03) @flagged
```

This would turn into

```
{"name":"Post to StackOverflow", "priority": 2, "due":"2016-05-03", "flagged":"value"}
```

Flagged doesn't need a value and all I can think of is to use `true` or `null`

I would like to later filter tasks using `if key in object` and having true/false values wouldn't work with my workflow.

What would the SO community recommend as best practices.

Comment: Omitting a property to indicate that it does not exist or is not available is perfectly acceptable approach. This is not "a key without a value"; it's "the absence of a key".

Comment: By specification of JSON, each key must have a value. Why are you avoiding true / false? If you want it to be short, you can use "f" : 0 / 1 . Or use compression when distributing JSON.

Comment: @torazaburo What does that look like?

Comment: @IvanKuckir True/False just feels messy to me, especially if the key is not present when the value would be false. I would never have a "false" value.

Comment: I mean, simply omit the property, as in `{"name": "...", "priority": 2, "due": "..."}`.

Comment: But you need to distinguish between flagged / unflagged values? If it looks messy, make your own binary format, convert it into string using base64 and use { "data": "string" }. It will be definitely much shorter. You can use one bit for that.

Comment: @IvanKuckir There are some properties that are just keys (like flagged) and other properties that have values and keys. But JSON afaik only allows key-val pairs. What is the best practice for a dummy val.

Comment: @MattBurland I want to mark your comment as the accepted answer.

Comment: To me, true / false is not messy at all, it is beautiful. Of course you can have a key without a value. Just edit your current parser and encoder. And I recommend not to call it JSON.  I think XML supports keys without values.

Comment: @JonathanWheeler: Done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do something like `if (myobj.flagged)`, then if your value of `flagged` is `true`, the test passes. If the `flagged` property doesn't exist, then you get `undefined` which is *falsy*. So it works with `flagged:true`, `flagged:false` and even no `flagged` property. So use `true`, and omit the property altogether when it's not supposed to be there (so `for...in` would work in that case).

Answer (score 4):

The JSON specification won't let you create a key in an object without some value, and there isn't a definition of "undefined" ([you can see here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) that the keywords are `null`, `true`, and `false`). If you're looking for a simple flag value, then your alternate approach could be:

```
if(object.key) // this would mean that the object has "key" and it is set 
               // to a truthy value.
```

Your other alternative might be something like:

```
if(key in object && object[key]) // Verifies key exists and has truthy value
```

Now, that being said, in ***JavaScript***, you can be a little more expressive. For example:

```
> var k;
undefined
> var o = {k:k}
undefined
> o
Object {k: undefined}
> console.log('k' in o)
true
```